# Using Chrome Dev tool as CSS editor for react or how to share changes made in chrome dev tool with react developer

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

As documented in the Chrome Dev tool documentation, React framework not supported for the CSS Overrides and Workspace so i can not enjoy the powerful abilities of chrome dev tools to edit CSS on the fly and save them for sending the CSS changes to the React developer for implementation in the code.

I also tried to use the new "Changes Tab" and i see that when i am changing the CSS properties using element inspector, i see on the chrome "Changes Tab" the changes in the big minify bundle file and not in the source mapping files so its hard to share the needed changes with the developer as a CSS writer.

[image]

So what is my question? How can i use Chrome Dev to make CSS changes but with an option to share the changes i made as a CSS writer to the react developer easily as possible.

Comment: Why do you need editation in dev tools? Most of react stacks have hot reload which will show your changes in browser on file save. 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-start-or-yarn-start

Comment: @ Miroslav Papírník - Good questions. Our CSS designer doesn't have an option to run the react project locally for some reasons.

Comment: What about some chrome extension like Amino? I see more problems in this approach. Production build can change your original CSS. (sass, prefixer, minification, uglify)

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @MiroslavPapírník I am not sure if you have ever done FE dev work. But its much faster and easier to test things on the fly.

Comment: @JamieHutber it's 3y old comment. Browser dev tools work much better these days.

Comment: lol ye fair play though I was using the dev tools to do these changes more quickly way back when there weren't any dev tools and we were all using firebug!! Though we didn't have hotrelaod back then!